# How to remove usb live boot?

Tags: live-usb

I tried the delete partition, delete volume, and formatting the usb but it didn't work. Every time I turn on the PC it makes me choose if I want to use Ubuntu or Windows.

[image: here's an image of it]

How can I delete Ubuntu and make the PC automatically use Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from windows command prompt: run
`bootrec /FixMbr`,
`bootrec /FixBoot`,
`bootrec /ScanOs`,
`bootrec /RebuildBcd`

If none of that fixes it,
You can get the boot-repair iso and make a bootable usb.
plug it in and boot from it and go to the option of uninstalling grub.

If even this doesn't fix it, then try the following: take from [here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/) )

1. Type these commands in order and hit Enter after each:

`diskpart sel disk 0 list vol`.

These commands will select the first disk of your computer and the list all the partitions available on that disk.

2. Check for the volume item that has the Fs column FAT32. The EFI partition must be formatted under FAT32. If the volume number of EFI partition is “2”, type the following command:

`sel vol 2`

If the volume number is different than 2, replace “2” with the number available on your computer.

3. Assign a letter to this partition, a letter that is different that those already available on your computer, for example x:. Type this command to assign the letter:

`assign letter=x:`

4. Wait for the success message to appear:

`"DiskPart successfully assigned the drive letter or mount point."`

5. Type exit to quit the DiskPart utility:

`exit`

6. Type this command and replace x:\ with the letter you assigned earlier to the EFI partition:

`cd /d x:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\`

7. Then type the bootrec command to repair the volume:

`bootrec /fixboot`

8. Now you need to backup the old BCD and recreate a new one. Type:

`ren BCD BCD.backup`

9. Type this command to recreate the BCD and replace the x:\ with the assigned letter earlier:

`bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s x: /f ALL`

In above command, Windows is installed on c:. If the drive letter where you have Windows 10 installed is different, replace c:\ with your drive letter.

10. Type exit and restart your computer.